# How to add the image folders to component that render an array in React

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

I asked a question here [How to join an array with folder images in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302558/how-to-join-an-array-with-folder-images-in-react), but didn't get any help.
So I was trying to change the logic, unfortunately useless.
I have Parent component with an array. This child component should render that array and somehow images from local folder. Folder name equal project.image.

Child component

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {

  const { project } = this.props;
  
  function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
  
  const folder1 = importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/folder1',false,/\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
  const folder2 = importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/folder2',false,/\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    return (
      <div className="portfolio-item">
         <div className="desc">  
          <div className="item-name">
            <p>{project.name}</p>
          </div>
        <div className="image-block">
         <div className="item-images">
            <Carousel showArrows={true} showThumbs={false} >
```

// attempt 1 (this works fine, but it's hurdcoded ... so it's not a solution )

```
 {project.image === 'folder1' ? folder1.map((image, index) => {
   return (
    <div className="image-block-small" key={index}>
      <div>
       <img src={image} alt=""/>
      </div>
     </div>
      )})
     : null} 
  </Carousel>         
 </div>
```

// attempt 2 (Here project.image equal folder1 (folder name), but here I get error "TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function", because the arguments passed to require.context must be literals!)

```
{importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/' + project.image, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)).map((image, index) => {
     return (
       <div className="image-block-small" key={index}>
          <div>
            <img src={image} alt=""/>
           </div>
        </div>
      )})
    : null} 
  </Carousel>         
 </div>
```

I tried even to make it like a variable

```
const folder1 = '../../assets/images/folder1';
{importAll(require.context(folder1, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)).map((image, index) => { ... }
```

but got the same response as was in the second attempt.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately,  I didn't get any answers to my question. So I've solved it using switch and extra component.

Images component

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const folder1 = importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/folder1', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
const folder2 = importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/folder2', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
const folder3 = importAll(require.context('../../assets/images/folder3', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

export default class Images extends Component {
  selectFolder(param) {
    switch(param) {
      case 'folder1':
        return folder1;
      case 'folder2':
        return folder2;
      // etc ....
      default:
        return folder3 ;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item-images">
        <Carousel showArrows={true} showThumbs={false} >
          {this.selectFolder(this.props.param).map((image, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="image-block-small" key={index}>
                <img src={image} alt=""/>
              </div>
              )
            })
          } 
        </Carousel>         
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Add put it with props "image" that equal to "folder name" inside Child component

```
<div className="image-block">
  <ProjectImages param={project.image}/>
</div>
```

Hope it will help someone else.