# Build an Image slider in react

Tags: reactjs, image

I can't figure out something very simple :-(

I'm building an image slider in react, with this idea:

- Import a `data.js` file, containing the image filepaths.
- the user clicks on a button and moves through the array.
- Of course, I cant import images one by one...

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import pics from './data'; //-->array with paths to images.
    function App() {
        let path =`./wallpapers/${pics[0]}`
        console.log(path)
        return (
            <div className="App">
            <img className='image' src={path} alt='dont know how will fix this, we dont have a way to generate alt content'/>
            <div className='panel'>
            <button>Left</button>
            <button>Right</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Now I'm confused since as this is javascript images won't be loaded like that. Is there any way to achieve this, or any technology I should take a look at?

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel. try bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: @EddwinPaz thanks, I've never taken a look to bootstrap so I will reinvent the wheel but next will do it using bootstrap :-)

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I recently had a similar question, I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312886/how-to-add-the-image-folders-to-component-that-render-an-array-in-react/63339023#63339023

Comment: Seems to. I just moved the images to "public" and they run fine. I'll give yours another read though. @Vova Thanks for reaching out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would need some sort of "current" image setting.  Clicking the buttons would trigger the value to up or down. Default it to 0.  This code isn't going to work as is, but the concept is like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import wallpapers from './wallpapers'

function App() {
        [ currentImage, setCurrentImage ] = useState(0)
        const path =`./wallpapers/${wallpapers[currentImage]}`
        return (
            <div className="App">
              <img className='image' src={path} alt='dont know how will fix this, we dont have a way to generate alt content'/>
              <div className='panel'>
                <button onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage - 1)}>Left</button>
                <button onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage + 1)}>Right</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In a separate file, you can import all the images

```
// wallpapers/index.js

import Wall1 from './wallpapers/1.png';
import Wall2 from './wallpapers/2.png';
import Wall3 from './wallpapers/3.png';
import Wall4 from './wallpapers/4.png';
import Wall5 from './wallpapers/5.png';
import Wall6 from './wallpapers/6.png';

export default [
    Wall1,
    Wall2,
    Wall3,
    Wall4,
    Wall5,
    Wall6
]
```

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that images arent loaded, it's the relative path from the App.js file right? or index.html? THanks by the way!!

Comment: Oh images should probably be on the public folder instead of source, right?

Comment: Yeah - you need to `import {}` each of the images too.  You can do that in a separate file and then export the images in an array.  I added some more code above to help explain.

Comment: But I've got 1K images XD, I've created a file with an array of the names pics=['a', 'b'...] and then  import only that array. It is running though...but maybe not the right approach?

Comment: 1k is not a huge amount, but you might want to figure out how to lazy load if your count is still growing

Comment: 1k I mean a thousand images. They are loaded as the user clicks on a button...